# Out of memory error in Delphi with ODBC and MidasLib

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado, delphi-2007

I have an ADOQuery connected to a DataSetProvider connected to a ClientDataSet connected to a DataSource connected to a DBGrid.  Under some circumstances, the query returns too many records, and I get an Out Of Memory Error in MidasLib.

I have read that I could use a DataReader, to avoid loading all of the records into memory, but I don't see how to use a DataReader and still have the DBGrid work properly.  I also can find no information about how to use a DataReader in Delphi.

I wonder if I can disconnect the ADOQuery from the DataSetProvider (and the rest of the chain), run the query, get the RecordCount, and then only reconnect the chain if the RecordCount seems reasonable.

I cannot figure out how to disable the DataSetProvider, and when I try to disable the ClientDataSet, I get the memory error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the ADOQuery.DataSetProvider to NIL and unloading all of the records directly from the ADOQuery into a local memory-resident database table.  It took a while, but there were no memory errors. The same data that caused the Out of Memory error, when converted to a StringList, was only 4 MB.